# ng-class is not applied

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I am trying to validate a form using AngularJS. This is my form:

```
<form ng-controller="LoginCtrl" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input required type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" class="form-control" ng-class="{ error: email.$invalid }" id="email">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The ng-class is never applied. I tried email.$valid, email.$invalid and email.$error. The controller doesn't do anything except for logging to the console, so I know it is called. When I do set `$scope.email = 'asd@asd.com'` hardcoded it is set correctly though.

Why isn't my ng-class applied when I enter no value or an invalid string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must qualify with the form name as well:

```
<form ng-controller="LoginCtrl" name="emailForm" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input required type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" class="form-control" ng-class="{ error: emailForm.email.$invalid }" id="email">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Angular has its own directive for `<form>` and therefore understands that if it sees a form, it should add an object to the current scope that is named the same.  In this case `emailForm`.  So, in the controller you would address the `email` field as `$scope.emailForm.email`.

Since, you are specifically looking for `required` you could also use this:

```
ng-class="{ error: emailForm.email.$error.required }"
```